# Are these lines of javascript code the same?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am refactoring some javascript code from a previous project where the developer is no longer involved.

To keep short and to the point consider this simple code in a .js file

```
var a;
a = b;
```

These are the first 2 lines of the file. Basically it is just creating a variable of `a` to reference the 'file global' (something defined in another js file) value of `b`.

But is this not just the same as doing:

```
var a = b;
```

Is it safe to refactor this simple change, or are there some hidden dangers that are not obvious?

---

If it makes any difference, `b` is just a simple object such as:

```
var b = { val1: '1', val2: '2' };
```

Comment: Search for [\[javascript\] variable hoisting](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+variable+hoisting). Such questions/answers will discuss the exact nuances of `var`. (The placement of `var` within a function is actually irrelevant; the assignment always takes place in the statement with the assignment operator and the declaration itself is always "hoisted".)

Comment: ..Then what is the point of this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two statements are identical. Thus `a` is just an alias for the global `b`.

Though we have to note that the arrangement of script references on the html page can cause a very popular problem. if the file that contains `b`'s declaration goes after the file that contains the lines:

```
var a;
a = b;
```

then the browser is going to throw an error.

***NOTE:*** The second example is just lighter in terms of JavaScript file size. Thus reducing HTTP request load which is not pretty obvious.

Comment: For some meaningless value of "reducing HTTP request load".

Comment: @user2864740, every bit counts in computing. Combing small pieces that were ignored can make differences.

Comment: See the 97/3 rule. This is not the fish you are looking for.

Comment: @user2864740, can you please give me a link sir? I want to learn about this 97/3?

Comment: See ["Computer Programming as an Art"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Literate_Programming_.281984.29) I don't like the other "famous" part of the quote; in any case I would use the code that was more clear to the task - maybe with the separation, maybe not. JavaScript minifiers - automated tooling that is independent of the initial code - get marginal gains by large-scale application of shortcuts (and renames and whatnot), but much of this is negated by HTTP compression anyway.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for the link brother! I'm gonna read this stuff tonight :)